# Why is SuperClass:initialize() different from SuperClass.initialize(self) in lua?

Tags: oop, lua

When using [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass) I encountered a strange problem:

```
ParentClass = class('ParentClass') 

function ParentClass:initialize(param)
   self.param = param
end
```

Now this will work:

```
Child1 = class('Child1', ParentClass)

function Child1:initialize(param)
  ParentClass.initialize(self, param)
end
```

But this wont:

```
Child2 = class('Child2', ParentClass)

function Child2:initialize(param)
  ParentClass:initialize(param)
end
```

Creating Children like Child2 will result in a modification of `param` not for the single instance but for all children that inherit from ParentClass.

It took me quite a long time to identify this problem as I was sure that `Object:function()` is just syntactical sugar for `Object.function(Object)` and thus should be the same. This seems somehow not to be a problem of middleclass because a different OO library I used before showed similar problems...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Child1:initialize(param)
  ParentClass.initialize(self, param)
end
```

is equivalent to

```
function Child1:initialize(param)
  ParentClass.initialize(Child1, param)
end
```

So `self` in

```
function ParentClass:initialize(param)
   self.param = param
end
```

will refer to `Child1`

While

```
function Child2:initialize(param)
  ParentClass:initialize(param)
end
```

is equivalent to

```
function Child2:initialize(param)
  ParentClass.initialize(ParentClass, param)
end
```

so `self` in

```
function ParentClass:initialize(param)
   self.param = param
end
```

will refer to `ParentClass`

So snippet 1 will initialize `Child1` while snippet 2 will initialize the base class.

Comment: You hit the nail. Obvious but I missed it for so many days. Thank you so much!